# why Indexed Nested-Loop Join only applicable for equi-join or natural join?

Tags: database, database-optimization

Indexed Nested-Loop Join :

For each tuple tr in the outer relation R, use the index to look up tuples in S that satisfy the join condition with tuple tr

some materials mentioned that "Indexed Nested-Loop Join"  only applicable for equi-join or natural join and an index is available on the inner relation’s join attribute

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA as a
JOIN tableB as b
ON a.col1 > b.col1;
```

Suppose we have an index on b.col1.

why Indexed Nested-Loop Join is not applicable for this case?

Comment: What are you asking? What is an indexed Nested-Loop Join? If this concerns query plan, then you should specify the RDBMS you are using. There is no SQL standard as to how the RDBMS engines are to execute the queries.

Comment: What you don't seem to get is that you do not get to decide how the query is executed. You can create indexes and other things... but it is the RDBMS engine that decides which is the best way to obtain the result set you are asking for. Your SELECT statments tells the engine WHAT you want. The engine decides HOW to give it to you. (Some RDBMS allow you to suggest a plan, but that is another matter)

Comment: @Frazz I am wondering why Indexed Nested-Loop Join only applicable for equi-join or natural join. Thanks.

Comment: The simplest answer is that that's the it database developers made it. As @Frazz says, you don't get the option. If you want more information, there may be some if you tell us - again as Frazz said - what DBMS you're using: MySQL? SQL Server? Access? Oracle? DB2? Informix? Sybase (which kind)? And so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quoting slides for Database Systems Concepts (c) Silberschatz, Korth and Sudarshan.

We want the DBMS to calculate a join. There are lots of special cases where it can do it various ways. These might involve whether there are indexes, selection conditions, etc.

The particular technique that that book calls by that name works in certain cases:

> Indexed Nested-Loop Join
>
> If an index is available on the inner loop's join attribute and join
>   is an equi-join or natural join

The answer is, because your query does not meet the conditions. It is not an equi-join (ie ON or WHERE a.col1 = b.col1) or natural join (USING (col1) or NATURAL JOIN).

As to why not meeting those conditions means not using that technique, it would be because it doesn't work and/or some other technique is better. You gave the technique :

> For each tuple tr in the outer relation r, use the index to look up
>   tuples in s that satisfy the join condition with tuple tr

If it's an inequality, you can't "look up in" the index; you have *search through* the index. Not this method.

Answer (score 0):

Well I read the second answer, so I checked the book called **Database System Concepts 7th Edition, by Silberschatz, Korth and Sudarshan**

First, like you can see, Indexed Nested Loop Join, can be used if an index is available on the inner loop, and we don't have any other restriction related to equality joins

[image]

I think the confusion is with Merge Join. In page 708, Chapter 15, Query Processing subject, we can see that this algorithm can be used just to compute natural joins and equi-joins.

[image]

Profiting the topic, just a mention about Hash Join. In this case, same as Merge Join, can be used just to compute natural joins and equi-joins.

[image]